# "Simpler" approach to this list comprehension + product() combination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with a mix of strings and lists:

```
sample_dict = {'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'ref': 'some text'}
```

Goal is to combine and "flatten" it into an iterable of individual dictionaries that will then be used as parameters for a set of scheduled tasks via Celery:

```
# end goal:
[{'numbers': 1, 'ref': 'some text'},
 {'numbers': 2, 'ref': 'some text'},
 {'numbers': 3, 'ref': 'some text'}]
```

I tried to write it using a traditional loop to keep the code simple for later adaptation or bugfixing but I couldn't work out a way that would have access to all the necessary nested variables.

Result was to use a couple of relatively complex list comprehensions:

```
raw_vals = [[(i,v)] if isinstance(v,str) else ([(i,b) for b in v]) for i,v in sample_dict.items()]
end_goal = [dict(i) for i in product(*raw_vals)]
```

Question therefore: is there a more verbose but potentially less cryptic way to get the same result, using a standard loop or similar? I know this potentially gets into a debate about readability vs LOC, but try to ignore that if you can.

Comment: ` is there a more verbose but potentially less cryptic way to get the same result, using a standard loop or similar?` of course there is, you can always do that on a for loop.

Comment: I did try @DanielSanchez but couldn't work out how to access each item of the main dictionary at once. For example, if you iterate through each key,value item you only have access to one at a time and can't return a merged dictionary. I'd love if you could reply with a solution for consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest factoring out the conditional out of the first:

```
def assoc(i, v):
   if isinstance(v, list):
      return [(i, b) for b in v]
   return [(i, v)]

raw_vals = [assoc(i, v) for i, v in sample_dict.items())]
end_goal = [dict(i) for i in product(*raw_vals)]
```

Then the comprehensions are maps.

I also might suggest testing if the value is a list rather than a string as this would permit values to be any type other than a list and not be iterated over. This would also permit subtypes of lists to be treated as lists.

Comment: Thanks @Dan-D - that does simplify the first list comprehension a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Either there's something missing from your question or you overlooked the obvious:

```
>>> sample_dict = {'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'ref': 'some text'}
>>> flattened = [{'numbers': num, 'ref': sample_dict['ref']} for num in      sample_dict['numbers']]
>>> print flattened
[{'ref': 'some text', 'numbers': 1}, {'ref': 'some text', 'numbers': 2}, {'ref': 'some text', 'numbers': 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno - I like this idea, but in my case the names of the keys will vary so they need to be abstracted. Should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Indeed - you perhaps want to edit your question then.